# how can i execute the loop again after loop finish using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

In my code i want to loop again once a certain condition if(i === arr.length) matched. here is the demo code. any idea how can i solve it?

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  setTimeout( function timer()
  {
      console.log("test");
      if(i === arr.length){
      // start the looping after this condition match
      }
  }, i*3000 );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but you can set `i=0` inside your if-statement to restart the loop

Comment: Your loop is finished before even the first `test` is written to the console. What are you _actually trying to achieve_. Essentially you've presented us an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RIYAL I think you should explain what you're trying to do, rather than fix what you're trying to do. I bet there's a much easier approach to you problem :)

Comment: Put the loop in a function and call that function whenever you want the loop to run

Comment: Also your if statement is never true since `i` will have values `0 1 2` and `arr.length` is `3`

Comment: In your current scenario it will run until i is less than length not equal to length. so you should make the check `i <= arr.length` and then it will reach inside the if condition. But what do you really want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never reaches the condition since i < arr.length is your exit,
if you change it to i <= arr.length then the condition will be reached,

then to re-enter the loop i suggest that you encapsulate all your loop in a function

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  setTimeout( function timer()
  {
      console.log("test");
      if(i === arr.length){
      // start the looping after this condition match
      }
  }, i*3000 );
}
```

To

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

function Looper(){
   for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
   {
     setTimeout( function timer()
     {
         console.log("test");
         if(i === arr.length){
             Looper();
         }
     }, i*3000 );
   }
}

Looper();
```

Keep in mind that this is an infinite loop, you would better use setInterval, if thats your goal, but if you have something else in mind hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code as it is now is the loop is exited before even the first `setTimeout` call back runs. The addition of a `console.log` after the loop confirms this.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  setTimeout( function timer()
  {
      console.log("test");
      if(i === arr.length){
      // start the looping after this condition match
      }
  }, i*3000 );
}
console.log("Loop exited");
```

So there is no way to restart that loop. However you can re-organise your code to keep looping over your `arr` with a 3000ms delay. The easiest is probably with a `Promise`.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

async function doWork(item){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("finished",item); // do whatever you want to do here
            resolve();
        },3000);
    });
}


async function test(){
  var exit = false; // if you set this to true elsewhere the code will stop
  var i = 0;

  while(!exit){
    var item = arr[i++ % arr.length];
    await doWork(item);
  }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple attempt hope you'll find it helpful

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var i = 0;

var i = 0;

function timer() {
  console.log(arr[i])
  i = (i + 1) % arr.length;
}
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```